# check if any of the values is `None` in `numpy.array`

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D `numpy.array`, which should act as indices for another, so it should contain only `int`s or `bool`s. Is there a quick and elegant (one line) way for checking for this condition?

I've tried the following code, but it does not provide the desired output, as it only checks for `0`s and not for `None`s, which is the value present in my case:

**Example 1:**

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
np.all(type(a) == np.int64, axis=0)
```

Current Output 1:

```
False
```

**Example 2:**

```
b = np.array([[1, 2, None], [3, 4, 5]])
np.all(type(a) == np.int64, axis=0)
```

Current Output 2:

```
False
```

so in the first example I'd like to get `True` as an output, as all the values of this array are numeric, while in example 2 - I'd like to get false, as there is a `None` value present in the first row of `b` array.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```py
(b == None).any()
```

Returns true if any element of `b` is `None`.

Note that `type(a)` will return `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` for any numpy array `a`. That is why your check always returns False irrespective of the presence of `None`.

You should check `a.dtype` for the getting the data type. That being said, any array that has `None` or strings in it will be of type object in numpy.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
a.dtype
# dtype('int64')
type(a)
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(a == None).any()
# False

b = np.array([[1, 2, None], [3, 4, 5]])
b.dtype
# dtype('O')
type(b)
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(b == None).any()
# True
(b == None).any(axis = 0)
# array([False, False,  True])
(b == None).any(axis = 1)
# array([ True, False])
```